# How to create a "Draw pool" of tiles using an enum in java

Tags: java, enums

I would like to figure out how enums works in Java by making an app that has a pool of "draw-able tiles" which gets transferred to a "player's hand". I am struggling with this concept, can someone help out?

If I have an enum like the one below, how can I use it to make it so that it has 4 copy of each of its values, making it a total of 136 "tiles" ? I would like to use those "136 tiles" as an exhaustible pool so that the user can draw from it and place the "tile" he drew into his own "hand" (also an enum I guess?)

**Problem:**
I use to have this feature using a plain string list but I have found an open source lib ([mahjong4j](https://github.com/mahjong4j/mahjong4j/tree/master/src/main/java/org/mahjong4j)) which 
I want to use. How should I approach this ? Should I create 2 new enums ? One containing 4 copy of each tiles and one for that player's hand ? Then transfer from one to another just like a List ?

This is the **Enum**:

```
public enum Tile {
    M1(0, MANZU, 1),
    M2(1, MANZU, 2),
    M3(2, MANZU, 3),
    M4(3, MANZU, 4),
    M5(4, MANZU, 5),
    M6(5, MANZU, 6),
    M7(6, MANZU, 7),
    M8(7, MANZU, 8),
    M9(8, MANZU, 9),

    P1(9, PINZU, 1),
    P2(10, PINZU, 2),
    P3(11, PINZU, 3),
    P4(12, PINZU, 4),
    P5(13, PINZU, 5),
    P6(14, PINZU, 6),
    P7(15, PINZU, 7),
    P8(16, PINZU, 8),
    P9(17, PINZU, 9),

    S1(18, SOHZU, 1),
    S2(19, SOHZU, 2),
    S3(20, SOHZU, 3),
    S4(21, SOHZU, 4),
    S5(22, SOHZU, 5),
    S6(23, SOHZU, 6),
    S7(24, SOHZU, 7),
    S8(25, SOHZU, 8),
    S9(26, SOHZU, 9),

    TON(27, FONPAI, 0),//東
    NAN(28, FONPAI, 0),//南
    SHA(29, FONPAI, 0),//西
    PEI(30, FONPAI, 0),//北

    HAK(31, SANGEN, 0),//白
    HAT(32, SANGEN, 0),//発
    CHN(33, SANGEN, 0);//中

    private int code;
    private TileType type;
    private int number;

    Tile(int code, TileType type, int number) {
        this.code = code;
        this.type = type;
        this.number = number;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are misunderstanding the purpose of enums. They are simply a class with a fixed set of objects. You can achieve exactly the same thing with a normal class and often that's a better option.

Firstly, once you have a set of possible tiles, the stack or deck of all tiles should definitely not be an enum. Rather it should be a `List` (or other collection that allows duplicates). That way you can shuffle it, deal from it etc.

Secondly, your enum name are really embedding 2 pieces of information - the type and number. This is often a sign that you'd be better off separating them.

If the intent in using an `enum` is to allow special cases for certain tiles then you can combine the approach by having your enum implement an interface.

Here's a potential alternative design for you to consider:

```
enum TileType { ... };

interface Tile {
    String getName();
    int getCode();
    TileType getType();
}

class StandardTile implements Tile {
    ...
}

enum FonpaiTile implements Tile {
    TON, NAN, SHA, PEI;
    public TileType getType() { return TileType.FONPAI; }
}

enum SangenTile implements Tile {
    HAK, HAT, CHN;
    public TileType getType() { return TileType.SANGEN; }
}

class TileSet {
    private final Set<Tile> tiles = new HashSet<>();
    private int id = 0;
    public TileSet() {
        // create all the standard and special tiles and add to set
    }
}

class Pool {
    private final List<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList<>();

    public Pool() {
        TileSet tileSet = new TileSet();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            tiles.addAll(tileSet);
        ...
        Collections.shuffle(tiles);
    }

    public Tile takeTile() {
        return tiles.remove(0);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return tiles.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

That way you can still use conditions like `tile == SangenTile.CHN` to code with special conditions if necessary.

Comment: I like your explanation, it helps a lot. Indeed, this topic had me struggling (still a bit). I wanted to use a list at first, and I did. But it intrigues me to see these people @mahjong4j are using enums to define their initial "tiles". I mean. that lib is for a mahjong game, there is no way that an enum containing 34 values will be useful on its own in a game where there always needs to be 4 copy of the initial 34 values (draw pool). So, I really wanted to get why they chose this. Can you think of any reason ? I feel I cannot move on without understanding this

Comment: Using an enum is a valid choice - it satisfies the standard use case of a fixed set of objects for a class. They may be using an enum because they have special cases regarding individual tiles (rather than types of tiles) they want to handle elsewhere in their code. So they want to compare to an enum member rather than a string comparison. That could well make sense. In fact you can combine the approaches because enums can implement interfaces. I'll give an example of that in my answer for your interest.

Comment: Very interesting. I've marked your initial reply as the answer to my question. Thank you for editing it even further. This will keep me busy for a while but I am able to dive into this topic with better clarity now.